# Correlate each raster layer in a brick with values in a dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe, correlation, raster

I have this dataframe in R:

```
library(raster)    

# create a random dataframe with yearly values for each column
df <- data.frame(year = seq(1981,2012), a = runif(32,1,33), b = rnorm(32, 6, 18), c = rnorm(32, 3, 12), 
                 d = rnorm(32, 0, 18))
```

and then this multilayer raster:

```
rs <- stack()

for (i in 1:1:32){
  xy <- matrix(rnorm(400),20,20)
  # Turn the matrix into a raster
  rast <- raster(xy)
  # Give it lat/lon coords for 20-30°E, 43-49°N
  extent(rast) <- c(20,30,43,49)
  rs <- addLayer(rs, rast)
}


# create a Z field for raster just created
years <- seq(as.Date("1981-01-01"), as.Date("2012-12-31"), by = "years")
aa <- setZ(rs, years)
names(rs) <- years
```

My question is: how would it be possible to obtain five rasters representing the correlation (let's say Spearman) between each column in dataframe **df** and the raster stack **rs**?

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured out a solution; don't know if is the best but I think is working. 
Here is the example for column a from df; I created a dummy raster layer for each row in column a; after that, I used corLocal to have the correlation:

```
### create a raster layer for each row (year) for column 'a' in df
rs.r <- stack()
library(data.table)

### extract x and y coordinates for raster rs to create a raster stack 
cord <- rasterToPoints(rs[[1]], spatial = F)
cord<- cord[,1:2]
head(cord)

### create a raster where each layer is the value in column a from df
year.s <- unique(df$year)

for (i in 1:length(df$year)){
  print(df$year[i])
  re <- df$a[df$year==year.s[i]]
  c <- data.table(x = cord[,1], y = cord[,2], tt = re)
  m <- rasterFromXYZ(c)
  crs(m) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 "
  rs.r <- addLayer(rs.r, m)
  crs(rs.r) <-" +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
}

names(rs.r) <- df$year ### set the names for the layers

ext <- extent(rs)
rs.r <- setExtent(rs.r, ext)


rs.r<- projectRaster(rs.r, rs,method = 'ngb')

spplot(corLocal(rs.r, rs, 'spearman'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what exactly you want to do. There are 32 values in each column of `df`, and 32 layers with 400 values in the RasterStack,

Perhaps you are looking for the correlation of the columns in `df` and the mean value of the layers? That you can do like this:

Your data

```
set.seed(0)
df <- data.frame(year = seq(1981,2012), a=runif(32,1,33), b=rnorm(32, 6, 18), c=rnorm(32, 3, 12), d=rnorm(32, 0, 18))
r <- raster(nrow=20, ncol=20, ext=extent(20,30,43,49))
rs <- stack(lapply(1:32, function(i) setValues(r, rnorm(400,20,20))))
years <- seq(as.Date("1981-01-01"), as.Date("2012-12-31"), by = "years")
names(rs) <- years
```

Solution

```
x <- cellStats(rs, mean)
sapply(2:5, function(i) cor(x, df[,i]))
#[1]  0.123391584 -0.007801092 -0.124336155  0.060774465
```

Comment: thanks for the tip. I am looking actually to get a correlation raster for each column from the **df** with the values from the **rs**. Basically, the correlation for each pixel from the raster stack with the values from the df for each column, based on the year column. The results should be a stack with 5 layers (as you will obtain with the corLocal function). However, I will try to build something on your example.

Comment: To compute correlation you need two vectors of the same length. You want to compare 1 value with 32 values. You could compute some statistic with that, but not a correlation coefficient.